# Get place details by reference - Google Map - Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I have a problem with display json url from google.
When i load my webpage i have a empty screen... no errors, no response

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CpQBhQAAAO74ZZ0bYHAkFKV3rXb-sMyPIvTUaP8olqsu61cyWIR-f3bTpcN0PU_VA3RWTLyH3NeJLWxOpXBqmczZDfYE6EnYbayYl6HWn4xNZA8fJURcNiY4dbzWaTfjxx9HDe3C1JCLZUDRqHwlVudODDRmUsiiJMVSMJniKyimt9-qGgn1paABdlGXU7uduPHUjy9hoxIQr4QJPQjk5yt9FXzzFJnhQxoU3NRNlO-q1Q8y36urd8F_lsvgWHY&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDSKYz8pCRLHglMPGo1ca6E-geDUQw', function(data) {
    $('#dictionary').empty();

 var html = '<div class="entry">';
 html += '<h3 class="term">' + data.result.name + '</h3>';
 html += '<div class="part">' + data.result.website + '</div>';
 html += '<div class="definition">';
 html +=  data.result.rating;
 html += '</div>';
 html += '</div>';
 $('#dictionary').append(html);


   });
 });
```

Url is correct, structure of json is also correct.
Function works good only when i want read json from file for example (not from url):

```
$.getJSON('fileofjson.json'......
```

Thanks for help. Michal.

PS.
[Parsing JSON from Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054804/parsing-json-from-google-map) This is my first topic of this problem... here is a structure of json file.

I try to read json from google by:

```
 $('#container').load('http://google.com'); 
  $.ajax({
url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CpQBhQAAAO74ZZ0bYHAkFKV3rXb-sMyPIvTUaP8olqsu61cyWIR-f3bTpcN0PU_VA3RWTLyH3NeJLWxOpXBqmczZDfYE6EnYbayYl6HWn4xNZA8fJURcNiY4dbzWaTfjxx9HDe3C1JCLZUDRqHwlVudODDRmUsiiJMVSMJniKyimt9-qGgn1paABdlGXU7uduPHUjy9hoxIQr4QJPQjk5yt9FXzzFJnhQxoU3NRNlO-q1Q8y36urd8F_lsvgWHY&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDSKYz8pCRLHglMPGo1ca6E-geDUQw',
type: 'GET',
success: function(res) {
    var headline = $(res.status).find('a.tsh').text();
    alert(headline);
}
});
```

but alert doesn't work, empty screen. Can somebody help me to parse this url to html? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673538/loading-json-data-from-an-api-from-javascript) and my answer. You can't, in general, load JSON from a remote source using Javascript, because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You'll need to use JSONP instead, if the Google API offers this.